# Quitting excel in C++ automation gives an error "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" when TFS Add in present

Tags: c++, excel

I have a C++ application using automation to read from excel files. The Excel wrapper classes were created using `Office14`. However on my system I just have `Office15`.
I open the Excel in the background and read data from the excel and display the data in my UI. Everything is fine till I do a quit on the `App` when I get an error "Microsoft Excel has stopped working".

Surprisingly I do not get this error if I disable the `TFS Add-In` for `VS 9.0` in `EXCEL` on my system.

I cannot make sense as to why the add-in is interfering with the application close from code. As soon as I disable this `Add-in` everything works fine and `EXCEL` closes in the background without error. 
I have the following code to quit `EXCEL` app.

```
CExcelApplication excelApp;
CExcelWorkbooks pBooks;
CExcelWorkbook workbook;
CExcelWorksheets pSheets;
CExcelWorksheet pSheet;
CExcelRange oRange;

if ( FAILED( excelApp.CreateDispatch( _T("Excel.Application") ) ) )
{
return;
}
COleVariant varOption( (long) DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR );
pBooks = excelApp.get_Workbooks();
workbook =  pBooks.Open( m_strFileName, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption, varOption);

pSheets = workbook.get_Worksheets();
pSheet = pSheets.get_Item(COleVariant((short)1));
oRange = pSheet.get_UsedRange();
COleSafeArray saRet(oRange.get_Value(varOption));

long iRows;
long iCols;
saRet.GetUBound(1, &iRows);
saRet.GetUBound(2, &iCols);

// Loop through the data and report the contents.
for (int rowCounter = 1; rowCounter <= iRows; rowCounter++) {
for (int colCounter = 1; colCounter <= iCols; colCounter++) {
    ...     }
}
////// Don't save any inadvertant changes to the .xls file.
oRange.ReleaseDispatch();
pSheet.ReleaseDispatch();
pSheets.ReleaseDispatch();
pSheet = NULL;
pSheets = NULL;

workbook.Close(COleVariant((short)FALSE), varOption, varOption);
workbook.ReleaseDispatch();
workbook = NULL;

pBooks.Close();
pBooks.ReleaseDispatch();
pBooks = NULL;

excelApp.Quit();
excelApp.ReleaseDispatch();
excelApp = NULL;
```